# Type aliases in Avro?

Tags: types, avro

Is it possible to create type aliases/synonyms in Avro (or approximate the same)?

I would like to flag e.g. that a "long" is a time-in-ms-since-epoch, without having to rely on the implicit context.

In Haskell terms, it would be something like:

```
type EpochTime = Double
```

In Scala terms similar:

```
type Coordinates = Tuple2[Float, Float]
```

Is there a similar way of doing this in Avro, or would I have to attach some additional metadata? [This thread](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AVRO-739) implies that I might have to use a record wrapper like so:

```
{"type": "record", "name":"epochTimeRecord", "fields" : [
  {"name": "epochTime", "type": "long"}
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Avro 1.7.5, there is no concept of aliasing in the haskell/scala sense you are describing.